# Change starting id number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an 'Account' model in Rails with its corresponding 'accounts' table in the database.  If I wipe the database and start over, the 'account_id' field will always start at 1 and count up from there.  I would like to change the starting number, so that, when the very first account is created in a fresh database, the 'account_id' is, say, 1000.  Is there a way to do that in Rails, or do I need specialized database-dependent SQL code?

For the sake of illustration, here is a simplified version of my 'accounts' table:

```
create_table "accounts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "email", :null => false
  t.string   "crypted_password", :null => false
  t.string   "name", :null => false
  t.boolean  "email_verified", :default => false
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to do some specialized database-dependent SQL to get this functionality.

If you're using MySQL, you can add the following code to your migration after the `create_table` code:

```
execute("ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000")
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter!  This will definitely help.

Answer (score 17):

for PostgreSQL:

```
execute("ALTER SEQUENCE accounts_id_seq START with 1000 RESTART;")
```

see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html

Comment: And in case people aren't aware (I wasn't), to execute the command in the console, run ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("...

Comment: That command didn't work for me. But this did: `ALTER SEQUENCE accounts_id_seq RESTART 10000;`

Answer (score 5):

For sqlite

sequences are stored in the table `sqlite_sequence` (name,seq)

- Check first if the sequence already exists?

  `select name,seq from sqlite_sequence where name = 'accounts'`

if sequence.empty?

`insert into sqlite_sequence(name,seq) values('accounts', 1000);`

else

`update sqlite_sequence set seq = 1000 where name = 'accounts';`

Answer (score 5):

A pure Ruby, database-independent approach could be:

```
class MyModel
  before_create do
    self.id = [1000, (self.class.maximum(:id) || 0) + 1].max if self.id.nil?
  end
end
```

When you're creating lots of records at once, this may not perform so well though.

Comment: it could be like `self.id = [1000, (self.class.maximum(:id) || 0) + 1].max if self.id.nil?` to handle initial empty table situation.

Comment: thank you, that is a welcome improvement! -- updated

Answer (score 2):

Another possible concept might be to simply use a start_at variable in your model file?

Such as define a base number such as `start_at = 53131` and then...
Make an accessor method (could call it "key") which adds your `start_at` number to your database's real ID before returning it.

And you could make a attr writer method that subtracts the `start_at` before saving the key, that may not even be necessary depending on your implementation.

Example in pseudo-code so bear with me.

```
class FakeModel
  attr_accessible :name
  start_at = 53121

  def self.find_by_key(key)
    find_by_id(key-start_at))
  end

  def key
    (self.id+start_at)
  end
end
```

Not sure how practical this is or if it would even work 100% but at least you wouldn't have to modify the database to handle it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach, while it would work, when you are looking at your database in a system other than your main, your ID's would all be wrong.  For example, if you connect your db to an analytics software, it would show the wrong ID.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Server:

```
execute('DBCC CHECKIDENT (accounts, reseed, 1000)')
```

In my case, the development environment and the production environment are using different type of database.

This code block will run the relevant execution accordin to DB type - just put it in the relevant migration:

```
puts 'Migration trys to set initial account ID to adapter:' + ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
case ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
  when 'MySQL'
    execute('ALTER TABLE accounts AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000')
  when 'SQLServer'
    execute('DBCC CHECKIDENT (accounts, reseed, 1000)')
  when 'SQLite'
    begin
      execute('insert into sqlite_sequence(name,seq) values(\'accounts\', 1000);')
    rescue
      puts 'insert error... updating'
    end
    execute('update sqlite_sequence set seq = 1000 where name = \'accounts\';')
  else
    puts "cant recognize the database"
end
```