# Rails 4, Rspec, FactoryGirl

Tags: factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble having an id column in a database that is not rails automagic. Basically the situation is the users table has to be between 5000 and 7000 and there are other external stipulations that don't allow this to auto-increment Here is the migration (which works magically in the console):

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :id, null: false
      t.string :firstname, null: false
      t.string :lastname, null: false
      t.string :username, null: false
      t.boolean :active, null: false, default: true
      t.date :hiredate, null: false
      t.date :termdate

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, [:id], :unique => true

    execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
  end
end
```

The problem I'm having is with testing in order to create a user with the factory I have to have a begin rescue block. The first time it fails and the second time it works perfectly. I have no idea why this happens. Here is the first part of users_spec.rb:

```
describe User do
    before(:all)do
        begin 
            @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        rescue
            @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        end
    end
end
```

I'm contemplating just having the id column perform as it should in a rails app and making a new extensions column, but I would appreciate someone helping me with this issue. Thank you for the help!

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075331/change-starting-id-number) help

Comment: You could auto determine the primary key by running a count+1 query, to determine the id to insert next?

Comment: It might help to post your model and factory code.